# Is there a way to avoid duplicated blocks in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, block

I have a block which I need to pass to `File.open` and another method `XXobject#read`. Since I passed the same block to those two methods, I would like to find a way to avoid duplicating the code of block.

I tried to define a `Proc` object, but `File.open` seems not to accept a `Proc` object. I am wondering why. As far as I know, a block is stored as a `Proc` object.

Is there a way to avoid duplicated blocks in Ruby?

Comment: use `&proc_object` as argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert Proc to Block:

```
blk = Proc.new{puts 1234567890}

def a; yield; end

a(&blk)

1.9.3-194 (main):0 > a(&blk)
1234567890
=> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

As already written in comment, you can convert proc to block using `&`.

Once you've defined `your_proc`, you can pass it as a block argument using `&your_proc`

Answer (score 0):

`proc = Proc.new 
&proc`

 it is block, block could used as a args for methods